# Image file not inserting into database

Tags: php, html, mysqli, prepared-statement, image-uploading

I'm trying to get an image file to send to a file I have in my host server called productpics/ and then send the file's name into my database with all of my other data in my form. I'm getting the image file to send to the productpics folder, but then my prepared statement breaks and nothing else happens. Nothing is sent to the db. I believe it is because of the way I'm trying to send the image file to the db.

The line I believe is breaking this is....

I'm getting this error with it when I submit the form, but regardless I'm not sure if I am trying to send this to the db correctly. Am I doing this the proper way or based on what I have, how can I structure this?

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/addproduct.php on line 110

```
//Create
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    //$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    //$filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_error = $_FILES['file']['error'];



    if (isset($filename )) {
        if (!empty($filename)) {

            $destinationFolder = 'productpics/';

            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destinationFolder.$filename)) {
                echo 'Uploaded!';
            } else {
                echo 'There was an error!';
            }

        } else {
            echo 'Please choose a file.';
        }
    }
    if($validation->passed()) {
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
            $product_id = trim( $_POST['product_id'] );
            $product_name = trim( $_POST['product_name'] );
            $price = trim( $_POST['price'] );
            $saleprice = trim( $_POST['saleprice'] );
            $final_price = trim( $_POST['final_price'] );
            $shippingprice = trim( $_POST['shippingprice'] );
            $category = trim( $_POST['category'] );
            $item_details = trim( $_POST['item_details'] );
            $item_details2 = trim( $_POST['item_details2'] );
            $description = trim( $_POST['description'] );
            $viewproduct_type = trim( $_POST['viewproduct_type'] );
            $file = $_POST ($filename['img']);

           }else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
          //Connection
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
        /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }



            /* create a prepared statement */
            if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_name, price, saleprice, final_price, shippingprice, category, item_details, item_details2, description, viewproduct_type, date_created, img) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)")) {


                /* bind parameters for markers */
                $stmt->bind_param('isiiiissssss', $product_id, $product_name, $price, $saleprice, $final_price, $shippingprice, $category, $item_details, $item_details2, $description, $viewproduct_type, $file);

                /* execute query */
                $stmt->execute();
                //if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}


            /* close statement */
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                echo "Success!";
            } else {
                echo "Failed!";
            }
            }
```

With all of that said, I am not getting anything to echo with my else statement for my prepared statement's query. I am not getting a 'Success!' or 'Failed!'. Why aren't any results of that showing?

My form for this(the img file part is at the bottom of it...

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="field">
    <label for="product_id">Product ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="product_id" class="smallinputbar" required>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="product_name">Product Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="product_name" required>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="price">Product Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="price" required>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="saleprice">Sale Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="saleprice">
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="final_price">Final Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="final_price" required>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="shippingprice">Shipping Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="shippingprice" required>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="category" required>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="item_details">Item Details</label>
    <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="item_details" required>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="item_details2">Item Details 2</label>
    <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="item_details2">
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="description" required>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="viewproduct_type">View Product Type</label>
    <select class="optionbar" name="viewproduct_type">
        <option value="Not Selected">Not Selected</option>
        <option value="a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id">Standard</option>
        <option value="Option">Option</option>
    </select>
</div>

<span class="floatright">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile">
    <!--<input type="submit" name="create" id="signinButton" value="Upload">-->
</span>
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <label for="button">
    <input type="submit" id="button" name="create" value="Create New Product">
    </label>
  </form>
```

UPDATE:

```
//Create
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    //$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    //$filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_error = $_FILES['file']['error'];



    if (isset($filename )) {
        if (!empty($filename)) {

            $destinationFolder = 'productpics/';

            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destinationFolder.$filename)) {
                echo 'Uploaded!';
            } else {
                echo 'There was an error!';
            }

        } else {
            echo 'Please choose a file.';
        }
    }

    if($validation->passed()) {
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
            $product_id = trim( $_POST['product_id'] );
            $product_name = trim( $_POST['product_name'] );
            $price = trim( $_POST['price'] );
            $saleprice = trim( $_POST['saleprice'] );
            $final_price = trim( $_POST['final_price'] );
            $shippingprice = trim( $_POST['shippingprice'] );
            $category = trim( $_POST['category'] );
            $item_details = trim( $_POST['item_details'] );
            $item_details2 = trim( $_POST['item_details2'] );
            $description = trim( $_POST['description'] );
            $viewproduct_type = trim( $_POST['viewproduct_type'] );
            $file = $filename;
```

FULL PHP code for this question.

```
//Validation
if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'product_id' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 1,
                'max' => 50,
                'unique' => 'products'
            ),
            'product_name' => array (
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            ),
            'price' => array (
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 1,
                'max' => 50
            ),
            'saleprice' => array (
                'min' => 1,
                'max' => 50
            ),
            'final_price' => array (
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 1,
                'max' => 50
            ),
            'shippingprice' => array (
                'max' => 50
            ),
            'category' => array (
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            ),
            'item_details' => array (
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 1550
            ),
            'item_details2' => array (
                'max' => 1550
            ),
            'description' => array (
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 1550
            )

        )
        );
//Create

        if($validation->passed()) {

        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        //$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        //$filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_error = $_FILES['file']['error'];



        if (isset($filename )) {
            if (!empty($filename)) {

                $destinationFolder = 'productpics/';

                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destinationFolder.$filename)) {
                    echo 'Uploaded!';
                } else {
                    echo 'There was an error!';
                }

            } else {
                echo 'Please choose a file.';
            }
        }
            if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
                $product_id = trim( $_POST['product_id'] );
                $product_name = trim( $_POST['product_name'] );
                $price = trim( $_POST['price'] );
                $saleprice = trim( $_POST['saleprice'] );
                $final_price = trim( $_POST['final_price'] );
                $shippingprice = trim( $_POST['shippingprice'] );
                $category = trim( $_POST['category'] );
                $item_details = trim( $_POST['item_details'] );
                $item_details2 = trim( $_POST['item_details2'] );
                $description = trim( $_POST['description'] );
                $viewproduct_type = trim( $_POST['viewproduct_type'] );
                $file = $filename;
                $file = $_POST['img'];

            }else {
                foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                    echo $error, '<br>';
                }

            //Connection
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
            /* check connection */
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                    exit();
                }



                /* create a prepared statement */
                if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_name, price, saleprice, final_price, shippingprice, category, item_details, item_details2, description, viewproduct_type, date_created, img) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)")) {


                    /* bind parameters for markers */
                    $stmt->bind_param('isiiiissssss', $product_id, $product_name, $price, $saleprice, $final_price, $shippingprice, $category, $item_details, $item_details2, $description, $viewproduct_type, $file);

                    /* execute query */
                    $stmt->execute();
                    //if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}


                /* close statement */
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                    echo "Success!";
                } else {
                    echo "Failed!";
                }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: plus these 2 conditionals `if (isset($filename )) {
        if (!empty($filename)) {` just use one or the other. using both is redundant.

Comment: also, if your folder does not have proper permissions to write to it, your code will stop there.

Comment: then this `$file = $_POST ($filename['img']);` why are you using that? you should be using `$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];` and rename `$filename` to `$file`.

Comment: The column I have for 'img' is text. I thought I posted line 110 in it. This is it......   $file = $_POST ($filename['img']);

Comment: When I make $file = $filename, I no longer get the error, but still nothing sends. I will update my question to show how I changed it.

Comment: I've noticed the same question from a week or so ago. at this point, I for one seem to be unable to resolve this; I've outlined a few things for you to check on above. What I suggest you do, is setup a new file, for just the uploaded file. Keep it simple. If that still fails, you'll know what to go after. Once you figure it out, then add in the rest of your code. Best I can do.

Comment: what is `$validation->passed()` and _does_ it pass? remove it for debugging.

Comment: I have simple validation for some of the fields above it, I tested it before and that is not causing this. I removed it as you suggested and it did nothing to help.

Comment: I really have to go to bed now. I've made a few more edits to my answer. Go over it again/reload it and go over it in its entirety and try and understand how MySQL and PHP work, they're different and work independently from each other. Mostly the one about *"If it still gives you trouble, use `$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];`"* - Remember, POST arrays do not determine the column in which it is to be inserted in. Use error reporting, it's at the bottom of my answer @Paul

Comment: @Paul has this been resolved yet?

Comment: @Fred -ii- No it hasn't

Answer (score 1):

Commenting back and forth is getting to be too long at this point and am submitting the following answer, since it is too long to be a comment.

Although this may not be a solution (or possibly could, or it may lead to one), is nonetheless an answer to the problem/error message you posted.

The problem is with this line `$file = $_POST ($filename['img']);` and I have no idea what you're trying to do here. 
You told me earlier in comments *"The column I have for 'img' is text"*.

- POST has nothing to do with a column.
- POST arrays use this syntax `$_POST[]` using square brackets, and not `$_POST()` with round brackets.

That is why you're getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/addproduct.php on line 110

- It's looking for a "function()" and you're trying to use `$_POST` as a function.
- $_POST is a superglobal (pre-defined/built-in variable), and not a function.
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

I don't know if you want to insert that uploaded file as a binary in your column, or a text-based pointer to that file, only you know the exact intention for it.

If you want to enter it as a binary, then you will need to set the associated column for it as a BLOB.

When using BLOB as a column type, then that data needs to be escaped, otherwise it will throw an error.

You will also want to check what your upload max size is set/allowed in your system files.

By default, PHP sets it to 2M. If the file exceeds that size, it will fail; increase it and anything else relative to it such as max timeout time.

You're also not doing anything with error checking in:

```
$file_error = $_FILES['file']['error'];
```

it's a stray/unused variable.

Consult:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

to check for errors and to use it.

As far as I'm concerning, I would get rid of `$file = $_POST ($filename['img']);` and use `$filename` for the variable you're wanting to enter in your database, since it is going inside the `img` column as you've set it in your query.

- Check your column length to see if it's long enough to accommodate the entry.

> *"The column I have for 'img' is text."*

- You may also want to change it from `TEXT` to `VARCHAR` and set a long enough length for it. MySQL may be failing silently because of it.

Another thing I suggest you do, is to place your `$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];` and other variables below that, inside your conditional statement.

---

If you want to use similar syntax to replace `$file = $_POST ($filename['img']);`, then you could add an additional input and give it the `img` name attribute and then do:

```
$file = $_POST['img'];
```

which would be valid.

---

Another thing I spotted in your first piece of code, and if that is your entire code, you're missing a closing brace `}` for your `if($validation->passed()) {` conditional statement.

The final/last brace `}` is associated with this block of code:

```
else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
```

- Therefore, you will need to check the bracing matches/pairs.

---

**Edit:**

In this line that you added in an edit:

```
$file = $filename;
$file = $_POST['img'];
```

You're overwriting your first variable, and you stated in comments that you do not have a form element name `img`.

But that is a file not text. Use `$file = $_FILES['img'];` or `$file = $_FILES['file'];` - at this point, I've no idea what your file input in the form is called.

- If it still gives you trouble, use `$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];`

MySQL and PHP are two different animals and do not know which column is to be used for insertion.

You cannot rely on a POST array to determine the column it is to be inserted in. You need to specify that in your query.

Make sure the `img` column does in fact exist, and then use the `$_FILES` array with its related variable as the value in `VALUES`, being `$file`.

- However, use `$filename` in your VALUES, instead of `$file`. Or, whatever variable; I am very confused at this point as to which variable and/or input name you're using.

and you may need to add that parameter in your `$validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(...` function/array.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help. I've been stuck on this for over a month. I wanted to do it right, so I started with learning my first prepared statement with this. So you know, I updated my question put in all of my php pertianing to this question other than a couple lines above that, that has the php errors and what not. In my database I hate the 'img' field table column set as text. I tried to change it to varchar, but it keeps changing it to longText. I am trying to send the img file to my database, not the actual image.

Comment: I went in and put my variables inside of the other part of this as you instructed. I am not sure where to incorporate the file error code at to check for the errors for this. The bracket issue was most likely due to the code I have above it for validation was not added. I am not sure if this has any issue with the problem, but the else statement for the query I added in is not showing anything. Does this mean the code is dying before that? So it is not echoing out a success or failed?

Comment: @Paul You're welcome Paul. Now I noticed you now have `$file = $_POST['img'];` does your form have an element named `img`? as in `<input type="text" name="img">` as an example. Yet you state it keeps changing it to "longText", I can't see how that would change it. When using `VARCHAR`, you need to give it a length and to alter your table accordingly. Using `VARCHAR(255)` is pretty much a safe bet, just make sure it's long enough to accommodate the file name.

Comment: @Paul if your bracing `{...}` doesn't match the if/else conditions, then yes... your code will fail somewhere.

Comment: @Paul and looking at your `$validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(` you don't seem to have one for the file/filename(s). Plus, check your `passed()` function. Something may be missing somewhere. Double/triple check everything and that there is no typos, or letter-case issues. `File` is not the same as `file` when it comes to PHP, in variables anyway, or constants etc.

Comment: No, I do not have a name 'img'. I get confused with the single quotes. Initially I was trying to use $_POST with the same logic as all of my other POST's. I though what went into the single quotes was the field it was going to go to in the db. I want the img to be sent into the file folder and then I want to send the filename to my db, so that I can use the filename to use the images. I altered my db and lowered the value and now it is staying at varchar.

Comment: @Paul that's not how things work. a POST array doesn't know in which column it's going into. You have to tell it to. `$_POST['img']` does not constitute as being syntax used for column names. POST arrays are for form elements only and form elements need to be given a name (attribute) in order for it to match up, and assigning a variable to that POST array, which in turn gets used in the `values` for insertion.

Comment: Okay, so my form, the file img input is named 'file'. So I changed my post syntax to...$file = $filename;
    $file = $_POST['file'];.. Still isn't doing anything.

Comment: @Paul `$file = $_POST['file'];` needs to be `$file = $_FILES['file'];` that is a file and not text. I've also made a new edit in my answer. But don't get confused by it. Since your comment above, you are changing it to something else.

Comment: Still nothing. I checked all of the variables and there is no typos. Is there any way I can debug this and break it down even further to see what is failing?

Comment: I have error reporting set already. In my form the img file field is named 'file'. I tried changing the variable to $file = $_FILES['file'];, but I left the other $file variable above it. I think the only thing I can do it try to break this apart like you have previously said. I will try to see if the prepared statement works without the file data and then I will see ifthe img file sends to my db without the other prepared statement data. I appreciate your help.